# php output buffering mask

Tags: php, output, buffering

From PHP manual: PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE const control access to functions: ob_clean(), ob_end_clean(), and ob_get_clean().

```
ob_start(null, 0, PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE);
```

Using ob_end_clean(), there is a notice: "ob_end_clean(): failed to discard buffer of default output handler (1)".

Using ob_get_clean(), there is even a double notice: "ob_get_clean(): failed to delete buffer of default output handler (1)".

I understand, that only cleanable buffer can't be flush and delete. So why in manual these functions are under control PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE const? I'm confused about using flags in output buffering.

Comment: Which php version you use?

Answer (score 6):

Passing only PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE as arg means ob can only be cleaned, not flushed or removed (ended). ob_end_clean() tries to remove (end) the buffer but flag PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE not passed so this is reason for the error. ob_get_clean() essentially executes both ob_get_contents() and ob_end_clean() so also error.

Passing only PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE as arg means ob can only be flushed, not cleaned or removed (ended).

Passing only PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE as arg means ob can only be removed (ended), not cleaned or flushed.

Passing (PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE | PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE) as arg means ob can only be cleaned and flushed, not removed (ended).

Passing (PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE | PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE | PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE) as arg means ob can be cleaned and flushed and removed (ended).

Similar result for all other combinations except note that PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_STDFLAGS is short for, or same as, (PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE | PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE | PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE).